# PHP convert string into object sub sub variable

Tags: php

I have the following a PHP object with the following properties:
Object:
-Advanced
--Data
To access it in PHP I would have to do the following:

```
$object->Advanced->Data
```

Now I want to define a string which has a syntax like this:

```
$string = "Advanced->Data";
```

How do I proceed from here to be able to use:

```
$object->$string = "Something";
```

So that in the end

```
$object->Advanced->Data = "Something";
```

I couldn't figure out using eval or $object->{$string}
If I try to use `$object->$string`
PHP creates a new property called "Advanced->Data", basically not interpreting the -> Operator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once try this,

```
$string = "Advanced->Data";  
$arr = explode("->",$string);
$temp = $object->{$arr[0]}->$arr[1];
```

But this is specific condition. Let me know your requirement if this is not the answer.

Comment: At least, down voters : let me know whats your complaints ? So that I can correct.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a hack, try this, it should work for your case

```
$arr = array();
$arr['Advanced']['Data'] = 'something';
$string =  json_decode(json_encode($arr), 0);
echo $string->Advanced->Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a hack, this can also fetch your desire

```
$string = &$object->Advanced->Data;
$string = "here we go";
var_dump($object->Advanced->Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably eval() is not best solution, but it can be useful in your case:

```
class obj2 {
    public $Data = 'test string';
}

class obj1 {
    public $Advanced;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Advanced = new obj2();
    }
}

$test = new obj1();
$string1 = "\$test->Advanced->Data = 'new string';";
$string2 = "\$result = \$test->Advanced->Data;";
eval($string1);
eval($string2);
echo $result . PHP_EOL;
```

Output will be "new string".